# Convert data frame to a list in which the double-bracketed index identifies each column

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I want to take this data.frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2), col2 = c('A', 'B'))
```

And convert it to a list having this structure:

```
man.list <- list(list(1, 'A'), list(2, 'B'))
```

I tried this approach:

```
df1.list <- split(df1, seq(nrow(df1)))
```

but it's not what I want because

```
df1.list[[1]]
```

gives

```
  col1 col2
1    1    A
```

and

```
man.list[[1]]
```

gives

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] "A"
```

How can I convert df1 into a list having the structure of man.list?

Comment: Why? This seems like a terrible idea. Anyway... `apply(df1, 1, function(x){unname(as.list(x))})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `split` by the sequence of rows, convert the 'col2' to `character` class, set the `names` to 'NULL' and convert to a `list` with `as.list`.

```
man.list2 <- setNames(lapply(split(df1, 1:nrow(df1)), function(x) 
    setNames(as.list(transform(x, col2 = as.character(col2))), NULL)), NULL)
identical(man.list, man.list2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or if the '1' and '2' can be also characters (which defeats the idea of storing it in a `list`) as showed in the comments

```
lapply(strsplit(do.call(paste, df1), " "), as.list)
```

Comment: @RHertel Yes, the assignment is basically the `names(A) <- letters[1:5]` which is also the same `setNames` is doing